# php how to get the hashtags from tabel

Tags: php

i want to get the hashtags from this tabel (sql), but sorted by most used - less used

[image]

example:

```
#gg (9 times i want to select first beacouse is most used)
#gogogo (4 times)
#simple_1 (3 times)
#simple_2 (1 times)
```

how to get it with php command:

```
$sql_query = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT FROM hashtags... ?')
```

Comment: @bub Tablename =/= Columnname

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes! You are right ... like always ;)

Comment: @bub Always??!?! Thats a long long time

Comment: @RiggsFolly Right again! Then...a small piece of always..the last months ;)

Comment: @bub LOL, I do try but I dont always succeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ORDER BY** keyword is needed to sort the table by `used` column. Like this,

```
SELECT hashtag,used FROM hashtags ORDER BY used;
```

Above query will sort the result in **ascending order.** (Less used)

**ORDER BY** sorts the result-set in ascending order by default, to sort it in descending order Update the Query like this, For that we use **DESC** keyword after the column name.

```
SELECT hashtag,used FROM hashtags ORDER BY used DESC;
```

Above query will sort the result in descending order ( Most used)

---

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

> The ORDER BY keyword is used to sort the result-set by one or more columns.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if that solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Using PDO:

```
<?php

    //DATABASE CONNECTION CONFIGURATION:
    defined("HOST")   or define("HOST",   "localhost");   //<== YOUR HOST
    defined("DBASE")  or define("DBASE",  "yourDB");      //<== YOUR DATABASE
    defined("USER")   or define("USER",   "root");        //<== YOUR USERNAME
    defined("PASS")   or define("PASS",   "root");        //<== YOUR PASS

    try {
        $dbh        = new \PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='. DBASE,USER,PASS);
        $dbh->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        // YOUR QUERY......
        $query      = " SELECT `used`, `hashtag` FROM `hashtags` ORDER BY `used` DESC ";
        $stmt       = $dbh->prepare($query);
        $resultSet  = $stmt->fetchObject();

        var_dump($resultSet);


    }catch(PDOException $e){
        throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
    }
```